# Game of thrones house card rules

Tags: game-of-thrones

A problem we ran into. Do the house cards stack or is what you play permanent. For instance, Baratheon play salladhor saan which makes all boats not your own 0 when supported. The opponent is greyjoys and play aeron. When they choose a new card they choose victarion. Would they still get the +2 to all there ships or would sans effect still make them 0?

Answer (score 4):

This is answered in the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/faq/VA65_AGoT2_FAQ_v1_4.pdf):

> Q: If House Greyjoy plays his “Victarion Greyjoy” House card against
>   House Baratheon’s “Sallador Saan” House card, are the participating
>   Greyjoy Ships still reduced to 0 combat strength?
>
> A: Yes.